# how to call another form on click of submit button of login form in sencha2.0?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working on sencha2.0. I have one login form and I want to call another form on click of submit button present in login form.

```
Ext.define('senchaApp.view.test', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype : 'test',
    requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
    id : 'login',
    layout:'vbox', 
    constructor : function(config) {
        var formContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            width:'100%',
            height:'100%',
            id:'formPanel',
            flex:1,
            items:[{
                xtype:'textfield',
                name:'user',
                id:'user',
                label:'Username',
                clearIcon:false,
                cls:'fields'
                },
                {xtype:'passwordfield',
                style:'margin-top:10px;',
                name:'pass',
                id:'pass',
                label:'Password',
                clearIcon:false,
                cls:'fields'
                },
                {xtype:'button',
                cls:'submitBtn',
                id:'submit',
                ui:'action-small',
                action:'submitLogin',
                style:'background-image: url("app/resources/images/img_btnStrip.png");width:186px;margin: 0 auto;height:66px;margin-top:20px;background-color:none;'
                }]
        });

        var formContentHolder = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            cls:'middleContainer',
            items:[formContainer]
        });
        config.items = [formContentHolder];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    initialize : function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Under controller there is Main.js, one doubt is what should come under ref and selector of refs:

```
Ext.define('senchaApp.controller.Main',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    refs:[{
        ref:'',
        selector:''
    }],

    init: function(){
    Ext.create('senchaApp.view.Viewport');
    this.control({
        '#submit':{
            tap: this.showanotherform
    }
    });
},
    showanotherform: function(){
    //How I will call another form on click of submit button here   
}

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Sencha Touch controller file, inside the `refs` section,

- `ref` : The ref is for the name or the getter method (first character is automatically capital). Stands out for the reference to use for this component in the future.
- `selector` : The selector is used with ComponentQuery to get the reference of that selector and cache it. It stands out for the `id (#myButton)` or the `xtype(button)` that is used to identify to which component we are refering to and trying to use it in future via `ref` value.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Another query that I have is what should I write in showanotherform function so as I can call another form with the click of submit button?

Comment: I think you need to use something similar to NavigationView, and making navigation to next view possible, only on successful submission of previous form. Check it out here .. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/navigation_view

Comment: I was thinking what if I make the layout of view as card and then add both of the forms as items.I know the logic here but feeling challenges in implementing it.If you feel idea can make out can u provide me some link where i can get some assistance to implement it? As of now if i replace layout from "vbox" to "card" then I am unable to see the fields of form.In wait of your response